# sprintf changes the content of an apparently unrelated array

Tags: c

I've spent hours pondering about this problem but I just can't seem to understand what's happening with my code (bit of disclaimer here: I just started learning C).

**Background**

I'm implementing a code which reads 512 bytes blocks of data from a file (till EOF) using fread() and if the first four bytes of buffer are 0xff, 0xd8, 0xff and anywhere between 0xe0 and 0xef, the program will write to another file till the next 512 bytes block contains the same four bytes identifier. Sample code is found below:

```
...

typedef uint8_t BYTE;
BYTE bytes[512];
while (fread(bytes, 512, 1, file) == 1)
{
 while (bytes[0] == 0xff && bytes[1] == 0xd8 && bytes[2] == 0xff && (bytes[3] & 0xf0)  == 0xe0)
  {
   for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) // Location 1
   {
        printf("Byte is %d\n", bytes[j]);
   }

   sprintf(newfile, "%03i.jpg", i);

   for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) // Location 2
   {
        printf("Byte is %d\n", bytes[j]);
   }

   .
   .
   .
  }
}
```

I added the for loops to debug my code and realised that Location 1 produces the correct first 4 bytes (i.e. 0xff, 0xd8, 0xff, between 0xe0 and 0xef), while location 2 produces incorrect first 4 bytes. Could anyone please enlighten me about why the location matters here?

Comment: What's the value of `i`? What's the definition of `newfile`? If `i` is uninitialized, it might have a huge value that might overflow a small buffer when you `sprintf` it. That would cause undefined behaviour, which might corrupt the contents `bytes`.

Comment: Your question title is misleading. It should rather be _sprintf changes the content of an apparently unrelated array_.

Comment: Hi M, thanks a lot for replying. Value of i is initialized as `int i = 0` outside the while loop. It's only for naming newfile in an iterative way. `newfile` will eventually be used in `FILE *img = fopen(newfile, "w");`, where a file is read and then written into img.

Comment: But how is `newfile` _defined_? That's the interesting part.

Comment: Thanks @Jabberwocky, changed the title (didn't know that sprintf is part of the problem). `newfile` is defined as `char newfile[6];`

Comment: The only thing that happens between locations 1 and 2 is the `sprintf`, so it's pretty obvious that the `sprintf` is the culprit for whatever reason.

Comment: `char newfile[6];`? For use with `sprintf(newfile, "%03i.jpg", i);`? Yeah, that's a bit of a problem there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `char newfile[6];`, `newfile` can hold a string of at most length 5 (you need one char more for the NUL terminator).

`sprintf(newfile, "%03i.jpg", i);` (with i=0) will result in this filename: `000.jpg` which takes 8 characters including the NUL terminator. Therefore you are experiencing a buffer overflow which is undefined behaviour which in your case manifests ifself by overwriting the `bytes` array.

You should never use `sprintf` but `snprintf` instead:

```
snprintf(newfile, sizeof(newfile), "%03i.jpg", i);
```

In that case no buffer overflow can occur, even if the `newfile` buffer is too small.

Comment: Ah I see! Rookie mistake and thanks a lot for your patience guys :) Have a safe rest of the week!